# How to make sense of the decryption formula for Affine ciphers?

Tags: encryption, modular-arithmetic, affine-cipher

Hi guys so I'm investigating Affine ciphers and I need to understand a field of mathematics I'm not familiar with, which is modular arithmetic. The formula for encrypting a letter $x$ using the affine cipher is:

$y = (ax+b) $ **mod** $ 26$

And apparently the decryption formula is

$x = a^{-1} (y-b)$ **mod** $26$

Where $a^{-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $a$ **mod** $26$. Firstly I have no idea how they derived this formula, but I think I have a general idea. I'm pretty sure they subtracted b from both sides and then divided both sides by a, but what to do about the mod26? Also what the heck does multiplicative inverse even mean? Like I know that it must be an integer, so how can that be possible? Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

About the derivation:

$y = ax+b $ **mod** $ 26$
$y-b = ax $ **mod** $ 26$
$a^{-1} (y-b) = a^{-1} ax $ **mod** $ 26$
$a^{-1} (y-b) = x $ **mod** $ 26$

Once you "got it", modular arithmetics is easy and fun ... don't be afraid :)

> but what to do about the mod26?

No reason to do anything with it. You have to understand it is applied to both sides. Following three lines are equivalent:

$y = (ax+b) $ **mod** $ 26$
$(y = (ax+b)) $ **mod** $ 26$
$y$ **mod** $ 26$ $= (ax+b) $ **mod** $ 26$

Maybe following helps to understand:
$n = 1 $ **mod** $ 26$
$n = 27 $ **mod** $ 26$
$n = 53 $ **mod** $ 26$
$n + 26 = 1 $ **mod** $ 26$
$n + 26 = 27 $ **mod** $ 26$
$n + 52 = 27 $ **mod** $ 26$
$n - 26 = 53 $ **mod** $ 26$

> Also what the heck does multiplicative inverse even mean? Like I know
>   that it must be an integer

In the real numbers (1, 3.14, -25.82 and so on), `x*2` and `x/2` are opposites, of course. `x/2` can also be written as `x*0.5`. Because *2 and *0.5 cancels each other out, 2 and 0.5 are *multiplicative inverse* of each other.

Tldr, the multiplicate inverse of `2` is `2^(-1)` and that is (according to the rules how "power of" is calculated) the same as `1/2`, ie. 0.5.

While modular structures are different from the real numbers, `a^(-1)` is still `1/a`, and nothing else. The number which can be multiplied with a to get 1 (1 being the "neutral element" for multiplications. 0 is the one for additions).

As for the two reason why straightforward division is not really used in modular structures, and how mult. inverse are calculated: A big problem is that some numbers with some modulus just have no inverse. Imagine the real numbers but only integers: What's inverse to 2? Nothing, because 0.5 does not exist. It's similar here.

$ a^{-1}$ **mod** $m$
exists iff
$gcd(a,m) = 1$
The gcd can be calculate with the *Euclidian algorithm*. Continuing the algo to the extended version, you can find x and y so that
$ax + my = 1$
Now x is the inverse of a.

A small example how to calculate `gcd(7,26)` (to get the inverse of 7 in mod 26 later):

```
26 = ? * 7 + ?  
26 = 3 * 7 + 5  

//move:
7 = ? * 5 + ?  
7 = 1 * 5 + 2  

//and so on:   
5 = ? * 2 + ?  
5 = 2 * 2 + 1  

2 = ? * 1 + ?  
2 = 2 * **1** + 0  
//now it`s +0, done, the gcd is the marked number 1, so 7 has an inverse
```

Second part (the [] are markers):

```
1 = [1]  
//always start with this

1 = [5] - 2 * [2]  
//where this comes from? Look into the last line of part 1, where **1** is,  
//and think how you can assemble it with the numbers from a line above:  
//[5]=?*[2]+?, [5]=2*[2]+1 so 1=[5]-2*[2]

//Repeat to replace the marked numbers (but NOT the rest,  
//and not 7 and 26 because they have no "line above")  
//and simplify until it's x*7 + y*26  

1 = [5] - 2 * ([7] - 1 * [5])  
1 = 3 * [5] - 2 * [7]  

1 = 3 * ([26] - 3 * [7]) - 2 * [7]  
1 = 3 * [26] - 11 * [7]  

So -11, ie. 15 is the inverse of 7
```

Comment: Hmm thanks for replying. I understand now that multiplicative inverse is just 1/x, but in terms of modular arithmetic how would I go about finding that? As in, how do I find the inverse of a mod 26? Do you have any sources where I can start learning this stuff? Thank you so much.

Comment: @ConfusedMathStudent Sorry, I'm still extending the answer :) Will write an answer to that too...

Comment: thank you so much, I'm very much looking forward to your response.

Comment: Added Euclid too (yes I'm currently bored)

Comment: Hmm I think I understand why now you  need to multiply by the multiplicative inverse of a to both sides. It's because you need to find an integer _m_ to multiply everything by such that a * _m_ is congruent to 1 mod 26, is that right? Since if you do that then the right side becomes 1 times x

Comment: @ConfusedMathStudent Yes, that's what an inverse element is. `a * a^(-1) = a * (1/a) = 1`

Comment: The notation used in the answer is confusing, non-standard, and different from the more correct notation used in the question, which correctly uses $a=b\bmod m$ to mean that $0\le a<m$ and $m$ divides $b-a$. Rather, the answer often uses $a=b\bmod m$ where there should be $a\equiv b\pmod m$, meaning $m$ divides $b-a$. In particular, per standard notation, $n+26=1\bmod 26$ can be understood to uniquely define $n$ to be the integer $-25$, and that's unwanted in the answer's context.